# Why this C++ Program is working having Character array?

Tags: arrays, character

Here is the code-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char s[1];
    strcpy(s,"BMWabc");
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

I have an array of size 1 but I am copying a string of 6 bytes in this array. It should show error. But the output is **BMWabc**. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It will work SOMETIMES only. When you are writing data to an undefined memory it may be overwriting memory used by other process or program. So sometimes it can cause crashing of other program.

Don't you notice when you install some softwares, entire operating system get hangs ?

This is called Memory Overflow.

When you print a string, it will print upto '\0'.